# oracle error while query execution :

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
select * from  Tablename where 1=1 and 
      decode (
             REGEXP_COUNT ('TEST1,TEST2', ','),
                          0,
                          TableName.Srcsyscd = 'CONCUR',
                          TableName.Srcsyscd='SAP'
             )
```

> Error while executing command: [Error] Execution (38: 64): ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Please help to provide a solution by using decode only

Comment: If you can write in words what you want, anyone can help. The query you posted is not making more sense,

Answer (score 1):

When putting `DECODE` in the `WHERE` clause, it can be used to remove rows that don't match some value. If that's your intent, you should compare it to something. For example:

```
select * from  Tablename where 1=1 and 
      TableName.Srcsyscd = decode (
                             REGEXP_COUNT ('TEST1,TEST2', ','),
                                         0,
                                         'CONCUR',
                                         'SAP'
                            )
```

If you want to show it, put it in the `SELECT` clause like this:

```
select Tablename.*,
         decode (
                 REGEXP_COUNT ('TEST1,TEST2', ','),
                             0,
                             'CONCUR',
                             'SAP'
                )

  from Tablename
```

In both cases it will make more sense if you replace 'TEST1,TEST2' with a column name.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wanted

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND tablename.srcsyscd =
       decode(regexp_count('TEST1,TEST2', ','), 0, 'CONCUR', 'SAP')
```